# Magento 2 change Ship button in Order functionality

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipment

I'm trying to change the functionality of Ship button when you choose an order.

The only thing that I have found so far is this file under /vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View.php:

I see this part where the button has an onclick method:

```
 $this->addButton(
                'order_ship',
                [
                    'label' => __('Ship'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getShipUrl() . '\')',
                    'class' => 'ship'
                ]
            );
```

and then this is the URL

```
public function getShipUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/order_shipment/start');
    }
```

I don't know if that url is a controller, I have not found a route with that id nor that exactly path. Or maybe it's an api?  This is the url that is shown on backend when I inspect

```
admin/order_shipment/start/order_id/60/key/ec0160f0fda15ac0271c4a0e1e2115471f7535673cc0e69f5c3af11deaba9ddf/'
```

Hope someone can give me a hint!

thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I wan't to change the status of the order when Ship button is clicked, to keep it in Processing or delivered

Comment: ah then maybe you can only do that using Observer, it's a backend process. try to look for events like `sales_order_shipment_save_after`

Answer (score 0):

Url is correct. The related module is **Magento_Shipping**. Check the following class:

```
vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Start.php
```